# Register RichTx32.Ocx in Windows 7 64 bit

Tags: windows, ms-access, ocx

I am trying to register RichTx32.Ocx  for an application I am working on in Access 2010 (File Format 2003 mdb). I have been updated to Windows 7 64 bit  (from Windows XP SP3 32 bit) and can't get the ActiveX OCX to register.

I have put the file in the system32 folder and get the following message: "The module "RICHTX32.OCX" may not compatible with the version of Windows that you're running. Check if the module is compatible with an x86 (32-bit) or x64 (64-bit) version of regsvr32.exe"

When I put the file in the SysWOW64 folder and run regsvr32 to that location, I get the following error message: "The moduile "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\RICHTX32.OCX" was loaded but the call to DllRegisterServer failed with error code 0x8002801c."

Comment: Why do you think you need to use an external rich text control? Have you given a look at the native A2010 control, which was greatly updated in A2007?

Comment: Access 2007+ Rich Text Control is actually HTML not pure Rich Text Format. In other words my RTF fields don't display using the text boxes. Furthermore it doesn't even let me change the property from plain text to Rich Text as it is a linked table to a SQL Server database.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are three obvious possibilities for this problem:

1. You are running the 64 bit version of regsvr32.
2. You have UAC enabled and when the OCX self-registers, its attempts to write to HKLM fail.
3. The OCX does not run under Windows 7.

I think the latter is unlikely and anyway I can't do much to help!

To get around issues 1&2 I do the following:

- Open a Command Prompt as administrator (right click on a shortcut to the Command Prompt and select "Run as Administrator").
- Run this command: `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\regsvr32 C:\Windows\SysWOW64\RICHTX32.OCX`

Comment: Ran that command C:\Windows\SysWOW64\regsvr32 C:\Windows\SysWOW64\RICHTX32.OCX and got the error: "The module "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\RICKTX32.OCX" was loaded but the call to DllRegisterServer failed with error code 0x8002801c."

Comment: Use Dependency Walker to check which DLL is missing

Comment: Should it be RICHTX32.OCX rather than RICKTX32.OCX? I just copied from your question, but surely it's RICHTX32.OCX

Comment: does using RICHTX32.OCX sort it out?

Comment: I gave all 3 of your a plus one (David, Alice, Rick).  This stuff is confusing the first time you try it.  Every bit (and repeat even) helps.

Answer (score 3):

Did the following and seems to have worked. Aperently, I had to run CMD in Administrator Mode, even though I am a local administrator.

(1) First, you must perform this on EVERY computer that has 2010

(2) Copy RichTx32.ocx to the following directory:  C:\Windows\SysWoW64

(3) Click the Windows 7 Start Button and in the Search area, type "command"

(4) The search will bring up a number of items, including "Command Prompt" at the top

(5) Right click the "Command Prompt" banner, and select "Run as Administrator"

(6) At the command prompt, enter:  %systemroot%\SysWoW64\regsvr32.exe RichTx32.ocx

(7) This should successfully register your OCX.

Thanks to:
Rich Locus Logicwurks, LLC www.logicwurks.com

Comment: Appreciate step-by-step explanation! Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

my english not good,so i hope you understand.

**Ran that command C:\Windows\SysWOW64\regsvr32 C:\Windows\SysWOW64\RICHTX32.OCX and got the error: "The module "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\RICKTX32.OCX" was loaded but the call to DllRegisterServer failed with error code 0x8002801c." – Rick Jun 13 '11 at 20:18**

ok in windows7 you need do this "user account control settings -----than "Never notice
"
---than reset ,

•Run this command: C:\Windows\SysWOW64\regsvr32 C:\Windows\SysWOW64\RICHTX32.OCX

it's gone be ok!