# My code is not working on some computer : Microsoft Forms Error then runtime error 424

Tags: excel, vba, debugging

I have a very large VBA script that perfectly works on my machine (windows 7, excel 2010).

However, when I ask a person to replicate the exact same steps (with screen sharing) on a windows 7, excel 2013 computer I have two issues.

First, when the document opens I have a warning concerning Microsoft Forms : Could not load object because it is not available on this machine.

Then, when the macro button is clicked I have a runtime error 424 from Microsoft Visual Basic.

Do you see how could I fix it ? If not, do you have any suggestions on how to debug this ?

Comment: Are you using any calendar controls?

Comment: @SiddharthRout No, there is no calendar controls.

Comment: What controls are there on the userform?

Comment: @SiddharthRout Checkboxes, list adn buttons. There are a lot of them. Do you think some form controls are not available on the other computer ?

Comment: "There are a lot of them.": Well, you are the developer. So do creating a test case having only one control and minimal code. If that works do adding further controls until it fails. Now you have the exact reason for failing.

Comment: Go to Tools -> References and see if you have any missing libraries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agreed with above comments. To clarify better, though, it'll be easier if you go on both computers and see the References; on the one that is failing you will see the missing one(s) and on the one that has all them - and fully functional - you can see if it is a dll, ocx, etc, and it's name; in the worst case scenario you'll be able to copy and register them on the failing one - if you need to register it [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6335546/register-richtx32-ocx-in-windows-7-64-bit) may help.

[image]

**EDIT 1:**
Sometimes I'm fooled by the dialog because it comes with the default - several formats except ocx - and I spend time looking until I remember to change the file type filter for ocx...